# Sound frequency detection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, algorithm, audio, frequency

I am currently attempting to create a sound frequency detection application on the iPhone. I have been informed that the algorithm I need for frequency detection of a single frequency is the goertzel algorithm.

However, I am currently struggling to implement this algorithm in C or Objective-C. I am unsure how to retrieve the data I need from the microphone and how to process it in realtime with this algorithm.

Any help / sample code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think the Goertzel alg tells you the magnitude of a given freq band, not the frequency of a signal. You might want to read up on FFT for that, but I'm not sure.